# Module Pattern: Restrict a module from being extended

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module-pattern, revealing-module-pattern

I've been reading several articles on Design Patterns in Javascript. I found module pattern easy to read/write.

I'm wondering if there is any way to stop extending a module in Javascript.

Here is the script that I've been working with:

```
var MODULE = (function(){
    var increment = 0;

    var funcIncrement = function(){
        increment ++;
        console.log(increment);
    };

    return {
        incr: funcIncrement
    }
})();


var moduleTwo = (function(MODULE){
    MODULE.extension = function(){ //This module will add extension function to MODULE. I don't want this to happen
        console.log('extension method');
    }


})(MODULE || {});
```

If I do `console.log(MODULE)` after running those the above snippet, then I'll get two function for MODULE (incr, extension)

Is there a way to restrict the `MODULE` from being extended when declaring the `MODULE` for the first time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can freeze returned object

```
var MODULE = (function(){
  var increment = 0;

  var funcIncrement = function(){
    increment ++;
    console.log(increment);
  };

  return Object.freeze({
    incr: funcIncrement
  });
})();
```

But it is not supported in older browsers.

Comment: Note that this still allows for override, for example `MODULE = {}`.

Comment: unfortunately, freeze wont work in IE8. Any good alternatives other than this ?